# HtmlAgilityPack Strip Nested Divs & Spans From Html But Keep Content

Tags: c#, replace, html-agility-pack

I have users trying to paste things like this into a text area

```
    <p><span style="font-size:16px">
<span dir="RTL">در وقايع تاريخي صدر اسلام لفظ <span style="color:#008000">
<span style="font-size:22px">شيعه </span>
</span>تنها به معناي لغوي آن یعنی <span style="color:#FF0000">مناصره</span> و
<span style="color:#FF0000"> پیروی</span> و متابعه آمده است، بلكه مي‌بينيم كه در عهدنامه حکمیّت و واگذاري حكومت بين دو خليفه علي و معاويه </span>
<span dir="RTL">ب</span> 
<span dir="RTL">كلمه شيعه بر پيروان علي  اطلاق شده؛ همآن‏گونه که</span></span>بر پيروان معاويه نيز اطلاق شده و به پيروان علي اختصاص نيافته است.</p>
```

As you can see it has many nested spans. I get the same with divs from some people too. How would I go about stripping ALL the span and div tags out BUT keeping the content InnerText? So I'm left with a chunk of text wrapped in the P tag?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

How about just using a Regex?

```
// Remove all tags
string clean = Regex.Replace(dirty, "<[^>]*>", "");

// put back the P tag
string result = "<p>" + clean  + "</p>"
```